# get duration of .mp4 file

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am making an application in .Net(VB) in which display a list of video files (.mp4). I want show to duration of each file as well. But I couldn't find the way how to got duration of mp4 file. Please provide and hint or guideline. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried getting the properties of the files somehow ?

Comment: You can use this nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Alturos.VideoInfo/

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the file attributes and get duration of particular file.this function will help:

```
Function GetDuration(ByVal MovieFullPath As String) As String
   If File.Exists(MovieFullPath) Then
      Dim objShell As Object = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
      Dim objFolder As Object = _
         objShell.Namespace(Path.GetDirectoryName(MovieFullPath))
            For Each strFileName In objFolder.Items
               If strFileName.Name = Path.GetFileName(MovieFullPath) Then
                  Return objFolder.GetDetailsOf(strFileName, 21).ToString
               End If
            Next

            Return ""
   Else
      Return ""
   End If
End Function
```

and call function like

```
Dim MyDuration As String = GetDuration("C:\SomePath\SomeVideoOrAudioFile.avi")
```

hope this helps!!

**Updates:**

in case of using a different operating system than XP, you should make small changes for the above code..

**if you are using Windows 7**, change

`Dim MyDuration As String = GetDuration("C:\SomePath\SomeVideoOrAudioFile.avi")`

to

`Return objFolder.GetDetailsOf(strFileName, 36).ToString`

**For Windows Vista Use** `Return objFolder.GetDetailsOf(strFileName, 27).ToString`

Comment: Thanks, but I a musing Windows 8, what will be number for Windows 8

Comment: This code only return string "duration" or "length", but i want duration in time (e.g. 10 mins, 15sec)

Answer (score 1):

**This is akhil kumar Code I'm Just Updating Some of it**

You can extract the file attributes and get duration of particular file.this function will help:

```
Function GetDuration(ByVal MovieFullPath As String) As String
   If File.Exists(MovieFullPath) Then
      Dim objShell As Object = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
      Dim objFolder As Object = _
         objShell.Namespace(Path.GetDirectoryName(MovieFullPath))
            For Each strFileName In objFolder.Items
               If strFileName.Name = Path.GetFileName(MovieFullPath) Then
                  Return objFolder.GetDetailsOf(strFileName, 21).ToString
                  Exit For
                  Exit Function
               End If
            Next
            Return ""
   Else
      Return ""
   End If
End Function
```

and call function like

`Dim MyDuration As String =  GetDuration("C:\SomePath\SomeVideoOrAudioFile.avi")`

hope this helps!!

**Updates**

in case of using a different operating system than XP,you should make small changed for the above code..

**if you are using Windows 7**, change

`Dim MyDuration As String =  GetDuration("C:\SomePath\SomeVideoOrAudioFile.avi")`

to

`Return objFolder.GetDetailsOf(strFileName, 36).ToString`.

**For Windows Vista Use** `Return objFolder.GetDetailsOf(strFileName, 27).ToString`

**For Windows 8 Use** `Return objFolder.GetDetailsOf(strFileName, 28).ToString`

**For Windows 10 Use** `Return objFolder.GetDetailsOf(strFileName, 27).ToString`